# How to create a dynamic textfield in PHP / PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, textfield, dynamic-data

I have a website where I need users to interact with other users.  So far all done in JQuery / Jquery Mobile and PHP with a MySQL database.

Users need to select other users to play against in a game, but may not know their exact username.

What I would like is a dynamic textfield that searches the usertable in the DB, and pulls back usernames that match the letters in the search field, so for example a user types:

S-A-M and the textfield returns all the relevant users from the DB, SamSmith, SamJones, SamBlah, then as the user types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yhat you're looking for is called "autocomplete"

You could do it yourself, however there are some plugins already developed to help you with that.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

You'd still need to code the query to get the user list on the server side.

Hope this helps

Comment: It's worth noting that the data will be generated with PHP/PDO, json_encoded, and sent to the browser when it requests a list of users to autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

This PHP code will be useful for that Jquery library 
"autocomplete.php"

```
<?php
    $q=$_GET['q'];
    $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);

    $mysqli=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db) or die("Database Error");
    $sql="SELECT name FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%$my_data%' ORDER BY name";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    if($result)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $row['name']."\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo "No Result!";
    }
?>
```

and

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tag").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
        selectFirst: true
    });
});
</script>

<input id="tag" name="product_name" type="text"  size="12"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a query to return an array of the users.
2. Then loop the users to HTML and enclose them with javascript codes for Jquery Autocomplete.

   ```
   $query = "SELECT id,username FROM users";
   $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
      $users[]  = $row;
   }
   ```

Then loop the username inside the jquery autocompletes available tags

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What do you mean by loop users to HTML?